# how do I layer images on top of another

Tags: jquery, css, append, z-index

I was reading another users question about how to layer images on top of another, using check-boxes.

For the most part I was able to follow the answer provided, however I am still facing the issue that the original poster had. For some reason the images are replacing each other instead of layering on top of each other.

**[Jquery: How to layer images on top of one another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817644/jquery-how-to-layer-images-on-top-of-one-another)**

- Update problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the general idea of the initial code was to use `div id="aluminum"` and `div id="aluminum"` defined at the most top as placeholders for overlapping images.

You are always using `$('#shirt').html(html);` instead.

That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#shirt').html(html);` keeps replacing the images. So at one instance, you're just seeing one image.

However, if you could explain in detail what you're trying to do with the code here, I could help create it for you.

Comment: I want to create a page that allows the user to customize a product. I want this to act like a really simple custom product designer. When a user selects a checkbox, it would layer an image on top of a previous one. In total there would be 4 layers each with their own options of colors. The images That I am using on this code page are simply test images, the blue one is transparent.

Comment: @user1522879 are you saying that each row of radio buttons will add an image to the top of the previous row ?

Comment: Yes, correct. I want the images to layer, which would eventually create like a custom product.

Comment: I will try to figure this out again...will update within 2-3 hours